# In MOSS 2007, in a pages library, error is caused when I click edit properties in Firefox

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In IE8, I can go to the Pages Library and click the drop down next to the page and click edit properties and MOSS 2007 checks out the page automatically and opens editform.aspx just fine.  In Firefox ESR 17.0.4 when I do the same thing, I get a server error.  But it does work in Firefox if I check out the page first and then hit edit.  I need it to work like it does in ie 8 where I do not need to check out first to edit the properties.

In IE8 when you click on Edit Properties a dialog box comes up titled "Message from webpage" and it says: You must check out this item before making changes. Do you want to check out this item now?

But in Firefox, I don't get that message, it just goes to the error page.